# Assigning reference of variable to pointer results in unintended behavior

Tags: c, pointers

I was writing a C program to calculate the Spearman Coefficient. It works fine but when I use

`*spearmanCoefficient = coeff;` I get this output: `Spearman: 0.01`

and when I use

`spearmanCoefficient = &coeff;` I get this output: `Spearman: 15707109983512927750860237824432537600.00`

However, `correlationFlag = &corrFlag;` gives me the correct output.

If I understand correctly, the first statement assigns the value of the variable `coeff` to the value of the pointer `spearmanCoefficient` and the second statement assigns the address of the variable `coeff` to the pointer `spearmanCoefficient` which should result in the same output but the output suggests that the second statement is referencing the address of the variable and not its value.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Thank you.

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

_Bool Correlate (int size, float arrayOne[], float arrayTwo[], float *spearmanCoefficient, float *correlationFlag)
{
    if (size > 0) {
        float sumOne = 0.0f;
        float sumTwo = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sumOne = sumOne + arrayOne[i];
            sumTwo = sumTwo + arrayTwo[i];
        }
        float meanOne = sumOne / (float)size;
        float meanTwo = sumTwo / (float)size;

        float varianceOne = 0.0f, varianceTwo = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sumOne = sumOne + pow((arrayOne[i] - meanOne), 2);
            sumTwo = sumTwo + pow((arrayTwo[i] - meanTwo), 2); 
        }
        varianceOne = sumOne / (float)size;
        varianceTwo = sumTwo / (float)size;
        float coeff = 0.0f;
        float corrFlag = 0.0f;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            coeff = coeff + (((arrayOne[i] - meanOne) * (arrayTwo[i] - meanTwo)) / (size * sqrt(varianceOne * varianceTwo)));
        }
        spearmanCoefficient = &coeff;

        if (coeff >= 0.9 && coeff <= 1.0) {
            corrFlag = 1.0;
        } else if (coeff >= -1.0 && coeff <= -0.9) {
            corrFlag = -1.0;
        } else {
            corrFlag = 0.0;
        }
        correlationFlag = &corrFlag;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    float arrayOne[10] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0};
    float arrayTwo[10] = {4.0, 6.0, 9.0, 10.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 8.0};
    int size = 10;
    float *spearmanCoefficient;
    float *correlationFlag;
    _Bool var = Correlate(size, arrayOne, arrayTwo, spearmanCoefficient, correlationFlag);
    printf("Spearman: %.2f\n", *spearmanCoefficient);
    printf("Flag: %.2f\n", *correlationFlag);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those pointers in `main` aren't pointing anywhere.

Comment: Your function isn't updating the pointers because they are passed by value. And if the pointers were updated, it still wouldn't work because they'd be pointing to local variables that no longer exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I understand correctly, the first statement assigns the value of
>   the variable `coeff` to the value of the pointer `spearmanCoefficient`

The first statement, `*spearmanCoefficient = coeff;`, assigns the value of variable `coeff` to the object to which pointer `spearmanCoefficient` points.  Doing this is predicated on the pointer in fact pointing to some object; if it does not, then the behavior is undefined.

> and
>   the second statement assigns the address of the variable `coeff` to the
>   pointer `spearmanCoefficient`

The second statement, `spearmanCoefficient = &coeff;`, does assign the address of variable `coeff` to the pointer variable `spearmanCoefficient`.

> which should result in the same output but
>   the output suggests that the second statement is referencing the
>   address of the variable and not its value.

The two statements perform distinct operations.  They have related, but different effects, so whether they are interchangeable in your program depends on the rest of the program.  Usually in such situations, which variation you use *does* matter.

As it turns out, *neither* of those alternatives is correct for the rest of the program as written.  You appear to be trying to return the Spearman coefficient and correlation flag from your function via pointer arguments.  In that case, you need to understand that in C, all program arguments are passed *by value*.  This includes arguments of pointer type, and it is the reason that if we want to return a value via an argument, that argument needs to be a pointer.

Your program provides a good illustration.  Your `Correlate()` function receives arguments `spearmanCoefficient` and `correlationFlag`, both of type `float *`.  These are *copies* of the caller's pointers.  Changes you make to the function's copies are not reflected by the caller's originals.  Thus, sure, you can assign `spearmanCoeff = &coeff`, and you can use that assigned value withing the function, but the caller won't see the result.

HOWEVER, the pointer copies in the function point to the same thing (if anything) that the caller's original pointers point to.  You can modify that thing via the pointers: `*spearmanCoeff = coeff`.  The caller will see the effect of that, but there's a problem in your case: the main program doesn't set its original `spearmanCoefficient` or `correlationFlag` pointers to point to anything!  Therefore, when `Correlate()` dereferences those pointers, undefined behavior results.  That *can* seem to be behavior you want or expect, as you claim is the case with `correlationFlag`, but you cannot rely on that.

You appear to have fallen into a common trap.  Inexperienced C programmers seem often to think that when a function wants an argument of pointer type, the right thing to do is to declare a variable of that type, and pass its value.  That sometimes *is* the right thing to do, though you must in that case actually assign a value first.  It is quite common, however, that the right thing to do is to declare an object of the pointed-to type, and pass its address:

```
int main() {
    float arrayOne[10] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0};
    float arrayTwo[10] = {4.0, 6.0, 9.0, 10.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 8.0};
    int size = 10;
    float spearmanCoefficient;
    float correlationFlag;
    _Bool var = Correlate(size, arrayOne, arrayTwo, &spearmanCoefficient,
            &correlationFlag);
    printf("Spearman: %.2f\n", spearmanCoefficient);
    printf("Flag: %.2f\n", correlationFlag);
    return 0;
}
```

That goes with the function performing assignments of your first kind, not your second kind.  I observe that I still do not initialize the `spearmanCoefficient` and `correlationFlag` variables.  This is acceptable because, with the arguments I am passing, I can rely on `Correlate()` to assign values to those variables (via the pointers I pass) before `main()` uses those variables' values.  If I could not rely on that or did not want to do, then it would be prudent to initialize those variables, or otherwise to assign values to them before the call.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

_Bool Correlate (int size, float arrayOne[], float arrayTwo[], float *spearmanCoefficient, float *correlationFlag)
{
    if (size > 0) {
        float sumOne = 0.0f;
        float sumTwo = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sumOne = sumOne + arrayOne[i];
            sumTwo = sumTwo + arrayTwo[i];
        }
        float meanOne = sumOne / (float)size;
        float meanTwo = sumTwo / (float)size;

        float varianceOne = 0.0f, varianceTwo = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sumOne = sumOne + pow((arrayOne[i] - meanOne), 2);
            sumTwo = sumTwo + pow((arrayTwo[i] - meanTwo), 2); 
        }
        varianceOne = sumOne / (float)size;
        varianceTwo = sumTwo / (float)size;
        float coeff = 0.0f;
        float corrFlag = 0.0f;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            coeff = coeff + (((arrayOne[i] - meanOne) * (arrayTwo[i] - meanTwo)) / (size * sqrt(varianceOne * varianceTwo)));
        }
        *spearmanCoefficient = coeff;

        if (coeff >= 0.9 && coeff <= 1.0) {
            corrFlag = 1.0;
        } else if (coeff >= -1.0 && coeff <= -0.9) {
            corrFlag = -1.0;
        } else {
            corrFlag = 0.0;
        }
        *correlationFlag = corrFlag;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    float arrayOne[10] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0};
    float arrayTwo[10] = {4.0, 6.0, 9.0, 10.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 8.0};
    int size = 10;
    float spearmanCoefficient;
    float correlationFlag;
    _Bool var = Correlate(size, arrayOne, arrayTwo, &spearmanCoefficient, &correlationFlag);
    printf("Spearman: %.2f\n", spearmanCoefficient);
    printf("Flag: %.2f\n", correlationFlag);
    return 0;
}
```